# Sketch 3 iOS UI Design not sync with actual design

Tags: ios, sketch-3, sketchapp

I am new to Sketch and facing a few issues.
As seen from the pictures below when I use symbols from `Sketch` default iOS UI Design, why does it looks smaller than the `Actual`. For example, the `Navigation Bar` and `Bottom Bar` look smaller than what actual seen in many applications and even apple's applications.
I am working on iPhone 6 platform with artboard size 375 x 667.

Secondly, I'm also working on iPod Touch. Hence do I need to recreate all my designs to suit the iPod Touch environment?
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

From Sketch using default iOS UI Design:

[image: From Sketch using default iOS UI Design]

Actual:

[image: Actual]